# I accidentally ran sudo chmod -R 777 /home/

Tags: chmod

I accidentally executed:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/
```

Is there any way to recover from this?

Comment: If you know how the permissions of some critical files need to be set, then yes. Better perhaps reset all user profiles and copy the user data back.

Comment: Please explain how you "accidently" ran a command. "Mistakenly" might be what you mean.

Answer (score 9):

Usually yes. You can change back to default permissions of `755` (directories) and `644` (files).

But you need to set permissions for some files, e.g. files in `.ssh`, `.gnupg` or `.local/bin`.

```bsh
# Set all files to 664, and all directories to 755
sudo find /home -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
sudo find /home -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

# Optional, set individual /home/ directories to private
# as it is default for Ubuntu > 21.04
sudo chmod 750 /home/*/

# Restrict .ssh directory
if [ -d ~/.ssh ]; then
    chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    find ~/.ssh -type f -exec chmod 600 {} +
fi

# Restrict .gnupg directory
if [ -d ~/.gnupg ]; then
    chmod 700 ~/.gnupg
    find ~/.gnupg -type f -exec chmod 600 {} +
fi

# Restrict access to .Xauthority
[ -f ~/.Xauthority ] && chmod 600 ~/.Xauthority

# Give +x for all files in $PATH
echo "$PATH" | tr : '\0' | grep -z '^/home' | xargs -r -0 -I{} chmod +x {}/*
```

- If you have more than one user, you can change permissions using `sudo` and `/home/*/` instead of `~/`.
- Note, that if you manually changed permissions of some files, you need to set this again.
- This might not be complete.